# R - The Means of Data Frame Function Returning not Numeric or Logical

Tags: r

I am a R beginner working on a self tutorial of R and working on the assignment. I have a list of csv files name from 001.csv to 332.csv. Each csv has four column: date, sulfate, nitrate and ID. I need to write a function to calculate the mean of pollutants of those files we call. So I have my code below,

```
pollutantmean <- function (directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) { 
  ## read the files
  
  filenames <- sprintf("%03d.csv",id)
  filepath <- paste(directory, filenames, sep="/")
  
  ## create a data frame to store data     
  df <- lapply(filepath, read.csv)
  
  ## calculate the mean
  
  mean(df[[pollutant]], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Everything is fine until the mean function at the last. When I input `"pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)"`

It returns

`Warning message: In mean.default(df[[pollutant]], na.rm = TRUE) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

I have tried class (df) and check it is a data frame, but not sure which part I missed resulting the df cannot be recognized. I have researched couple hours from different sites but are still not able to get the key. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue is that lapply is returning a list of data frames, and you are trying to calculate the mean directly on the list. You should first combine these data frames into a single object before calculating the mean.

Here's an updated version of your function:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
  ## read the files
  filenames <- sprintf("%03d.csv", id)
  filepath <- paste(directory, filenames, sep="/")
  
  ## create a data frame to store data
  df_list <- lapply(filepath, read.csv)
  
  ## combine the data frames into a single data frame
  df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
  
  ## calculate the mean
  result <- mean(df[[pollutant]], na.rm = TRUE)
  
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: Good catch! You do not need `return()`

Comment: Yes, in this case we don't need return(), however, using return()  can make your code more readable and I consider to be a good pratice. In some cases, inside complex functions, with multiple operations might be needd.

Comment: @Friede If I'm debugging a function line by line and forget that the return is a giant list I'm very happy about having it in `return()`.

Comment: @LuccaNielsen Thanks for the answer. It works and I like your idea to keep the return(). This helps me to build a better habit at the beginning though I was taught no need to put the return() at the end.